# Restangular all("customers").getList() does not return result

Tags: rest, angularjs, restangular

I started using Restangular to send RESTful requests from my AngularJS app. I have a REST service deployed on `http://localhost:20080/v1/customer` which produces JSON with customer information.

When I debug AngularJS app it hits a breakpoint in the back-end REST service, however in the browser console it always logs "Failed to find customers with status code 0". Moreover, I never hit the breakpoint in the function that I register as setResponseExtractor.

I also don't see any errors in the console.

When I open `http://localhost:20080/v1/customer` in the browser I get the following response:

```
[{"customerInfo":{"name":"My Name","email":"My Email"},"id":"6ca43d0f-94a8-36e8-af3d-963584573d6d"}]
```

My Restangular code is as follows:

```
var customerModule = angular.module('customer-module',
            ['restangular' ]).config(
            ['RestangularProvider', '$httpProvider',
                function (RestangularProvider, $httpProvider)
                {
                    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost\\:20080/v1');
                    RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function (response, operation, what) {
                      return response;
                    });
...

customerModule.controller('CustomerCtrl',
    [ '$scope', 'Restangular', function ($scope, Restangular)
    {
    var baseCustomers = Restangular.all("customer");
    $scope.customers = baseCustomers.getList().then(function (result) {
        console.log("Got customers", response.status);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log("Failed to find customers with status code", response.status);
    });
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with accessing REST services running on a different port than my AngularJS app.

I am moving this thread to AngularJS mailing list - ["Problems with a basic $resource.get() call"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/PanpwKPNkX8)

Alec

Comment: Hey, you can set the port here without a problem. Check out https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#when-i-set-baseurl-with-a-port-its-stripped-out

Comment: mgonto, I got it to work. The problem was with cross-origin request (CORS) from one port to another.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of Restangular.

You also don't have to add the responseExtractor to the config if you're just returning the response. That's what it does by default.

If you have any other problem, please contact me!

Comment: Restangular worked like a charm once I figured out the CORS problem. For details see my posts on angularjs mailing list.

Comment: @alecswan: posting a link to any of said posts would have been helpful.

Comment: I am having a CORS problem. Where can I find this post @alecswan?